I want Excel to interpret an operator as a caracter in a formula
I have a form with answers such as: < 24
or  > 20 kh
I want to count how many answer are of each type.
I want to use a formula of this kind: =COUNTIF(EW5:EW150;"< 24")
but it seems that Excel treats "< 24" as: inferior to 24, whereas I want Excel to treat it as a simple string of characters.
How can I do this?
Thank you

Something like =SUM(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH("<24",EW5:EW150))) should work.

Use a wildcard to treat it as a string --> COUNTIF(EW5:EW150;"*< 24*")

Yes! Both works fine. Thank you so much!

Or just put = in front of it: COUNTIF(EW5:EW150;"=< 24")

Not strictly on topic, but I wonder how you would count cells containing ">" only? AFAIK you would have to do something like =SUM(--(ew5:ew150=">"))

okay, "=< 24" works fine also. Thanks

I was wondering: what is the meaning of -- in front of a function (e.g., --ISNUMBER) ?

@TomSharpe Use solution from @Rory: COUNTIF(range,"=>")

@MayukhBhattacharya Your solution is very data dependent. It will also count any string that contains < 24

@Pascal The double unary will convert TRUE to 1 and FALSE to 0.

@RonRosenfeld Sir, I don;t think OP should have any issue for the one I have proposed. For this use case, it should work as already been stated by OP. Yes using =< 24" is also acceptable.

If you apply SUM and IF separately the required result is returned.
=SUM(IF(EW5:EW150="< 24",1,0))

Hello, with this formula I get an error next to 24"

If your local settings is not English/US maybe the separator is ;

Yes, I am using the French version of Excel. It works fine with ;. Thanks
